# Spring Security form login using database with annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a `login page` that works correctly when using in memory authentication.
But when i want to use `jdbc authentication` it doesn't work and i can't figure why.

Below is the code for my `App class`

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bookDB");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("postgres");
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("postgres");
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}
```

Below is the code for my `Authentication class`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class Authentication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().csrf().disable()
            .logout().permitAll();

}

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?");

}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

can anybody here help me?

Comment: any error or message log?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: login page does'nt work;there's no error but the log is:  ResourceBundle [messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is just missing the call to the method: `authoritiesByUsernameQuery`

Your code becomes:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username, password, enabled from users where username=?")
          **.authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username, role from user_roles where username = ?");** 
}
```